# Starting Android project with PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to start an Android app with PhoneGap. I follow [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzcIcyBYJMA) and when I hit the run button It shows me the following errors.

```
12-03 18:45:52.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27214): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tpl.apps.UKTrains/tpl.apps.UKTrains.Main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
12-03 18:45:52.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2705)
12-03 18:45:52.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
12-03 18:45:52.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:132)
12-03 18:45:52.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27214):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
12-03 18:45:52.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27214):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 18:45:52.704: E/AndroidRuntime(27214):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
```

Then I tried to run their example app the one with the phone informations and stuffs. It is working fine and I made some other changes according to sample app but it is still not working.

Do you have any idea what it could be?
Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution by myself the problem is the phonegap needs pluging.xml file under the res\xml folder.

Comment: I have plugins.xml and phonegap.xml - both in res/xml, but the problem remains.

Comment: well, I cannot say anything specific but try to compare your app and phonegap example app and libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Onur, but I deсided to code for Android nativly, as I know JAVA well - for other devices (iPhone for ex.) we decided to employ other programmers =) PhoneGap looks like Gap at all =)

Comment: It is a great choose this video kinda old but explains everything http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=It8xPqkKxis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just confirm what Onur already wrote: there are files phonegap.xml (called cordova.xml right now, after Phonegap became Apache Cordova project) and plugin.xml, and you keep getting the error above until you provide these two files in res/xml folder.

I had run into the problem while cloning my Phonegap project built with 0.9-something release, and upgrading the Phonegap files to 1.2, or Cordova 1.5.

Obviously I didn't pay enough attention to "changelog" files, because there were no XML files needed for 0.9x release.