# android phonegap downloader plugin 2.2

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I am developing a phonegap application which needs the Android Downloader plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Downloader

Unfortunately, it seems to fail using latest cordova (2.2). I've spent some hours trying to upgrade the code:

downloader.js

```
cordova.define(
    "cordova/plugin/downloader",
    function(require, exports, module)
    {
        var exec = require("cordova/exec");

        var Downloader = function() {};

        Downloader.prototype.downloadFile = function(fileUrl, params, successCallback, failureCallback)
        {
            // Make params hash optional.
            if (!failureCallback) win = params;

            return exec(
                successCallback,
                failureCallback,
                'Downloader', 
                'downloadFile',
                [fileUrl, params]);
        };

        var downloader = new Downloader();
        module.exports = downloader;
    }
);
```

Downloader.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugins.Downloader;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
[more imports...]

public class Downloader extends Plugin 
{
etc.
```

config.xml

```
<plugins>
<plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
[...]
<plugin name="Downloader" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.Downloader"/>
</plugins>
```

HTML JS call

```
downloader = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/downloader");

downloader.downloadFile(...
```

The app compiles fine in Eclipse but when executing the downloader code I get: ALERT Class not found. The logcat says:

W/System.err(4035): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.plugins.Downloader
...
Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.plugins.Downloader.

Can you help me fixing what's wrong?

Comment: have you tried this below suggested link ??

Comment: why don t you use cordova default plugin http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File?

And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370060/starting-android-project-with-phonegap as you can see here cordova also has a xml called plugin.xml can you please check that file to?

Comment: Eclipse, yes. I've already read that documentation. plugins.xml is not used anymore, now the configuration is declared in config.xml. I'll try the default File plugin but I'd like to know what's wrong on my files to learn how to implement other plugins. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in js file rather than done by you and all is working fine.

```
function Downloader() {}

Downloader.prototype.downloadFile = function(fileUrl, params, win, fail) {  
    //Make params hash optional.
    if (!fail) win = params;
    PhoneGap.exec(win, fail, "Downloader", "downloadFile", [fileUrl, params]);
};

   PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("downloader", new Downloader());
    PluginManager.addService("Downloader", "com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.Downloader");
});

if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}   
if (!window.plugins.downloader) {
    window.plugins.downloader = new Downloader();
}
```

Comment: In the end I used the integrated Cordova File object. I'll try your code in my next project. Thank you.